# feel something + adjective

Tags: grammar

http://www.globaltimes.cn/content/1123264.shtml

> Sun felt **it ridiculous** to portray a woman kneeling and begging for
>   mercy as the only means of solving problems,

I have thought an adjective always after a "be". This usage is somehow strange for me.

Comment: Feel is also a linking verb, so ... you may want to check it in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, '***feel***' in this context means: *to believe, think, or be of the opinion (that)*.

Compared to: *I felt it advisable to do nothing.*

Refer to this [dictionary definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/feel), sense 5:

> b. To believe; think: *She felt his answer to be evasive*.